# grep, memory issue

Tags: linux, grep

I am using `grep` to search inside the `/` directory, but I encountered the folowing problem:

```
root@debian:/# grep -rn allhwsupport
grep: proc/sysrq-trigger: Erreur d'entrée/sortie
grep: mémoire épuisée
```

I translated the message to English and it gives :

```
root@debian:/# grep -rn allhwsupport
grep: /proc/sysrq-trigger: Input/output error
grep: exhausted memory.
```

How can I avoid this?